# Program gives segmantation fault while using wildcard (*) as first input

Tags: c, pointers, memory, char, segmentation-fault

```
/*Input string argument can be up to 3 integer numbers, 
  separated by spaces.  A wild card value, represented by a * 
  character can replace any one of the integer numbers.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void parse(char *data);

int program = 0, version = 0, process = 0;

unsigned char flags = 0;

#define GOT_PROG 0x01

#define GOT_VERS 0x02

#define GOT_PROC 0x04


int main()

{
    char data[] = " * 10 7 ";
    parse(data);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


void parse(char *data)
{

    char *tmp = NULL;
    /* advance past whitespace */
    while(isspace((int)*data)) data++;
    if(*data != '*')
    {
        program = strtoul(data,&tmp,0);
        flags|=GOT_PROG;
        printf("%d 11\n",program );
    }

    if(*tmp == '\0') return;
    data=++tmp;

    if(*data != '*')
    {
        version = strtoul(data,&tmp,0);
        flags|=GOT_VERS;
        printf("%d  22\n",version);
    }
    else
    {
        tmp++;
    }

    if(*tmp == '\0') return;
    data=++tmp;

    if(*data != '*')
    {
        process = strtoul(data,&tmp,0);
        flags|=GOT_PROC;
        printf("%d  33\n",process);
    }
}
```

When my inputs are 3 integers it runs fine.
When my Inputs are two ints and one `*` it runs fine except when I replace  1st integer with an `*`, not sure where am I going wrong!! Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use `tmp` simply do `strtoul(data,&data,0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logic error in this block:

```
char *tmp = NULL;
/* advance past whitespace */
while(isspace((int)*data)) data++;

// If *data == '*', you are skipping the code inside the if block.
// tmp continues to be NULL.
if(*data != '*')
{
    program = strtoul(data,&tmp,0);
    flags|=GOT_PROG;
    printf("%d 11\n",program );
}

// Now you are dereferencing a NULL pointer
// and then setting the value of data to 'NULL + 1'.

if(*tmp == '\0') return;
data=++tmp;
```

I didn't follow the entire logic of your function but you have to add code that deals with the case of `*data == '*'`.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `parse()`, you're doing

```
char *tmp = NULL;
```

then, in case of `*data` equals `*`, (Remember, the erroneous case input starts with `*`) without changing `tmp`, you're doing

```
if(*tmp == '\0')
```

i.e., dereferencing invalid pointer, which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to take care of the access to `tmp` in case of the input has a leading `*`.

FWIW, in the same regards, `data=++tmp;` is also invalid.

**Suggestion:**  After seeing your logic, I suggest to tokenize the input string using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok). That is far better option.

Comment: @Saurav Ghosh  I got your point, but why would it work for these cases (int , * , int) and (int, int , *)?